# Laravel 4.2 Redirect::to with GET Params

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

Is there a possibility to redirect to an url with GET params using `Redirect::to()` in Laravel 4.2?

I'm trying to redirect users after login to requested page when they weren't logged in.

If you are not logged in and you visit authorized page, I save the full requested url in session (this url can be something like `https://page.com/settings`  or `https://page.com/post/23` or `https://page.com/post/23?show=full`. Lots of variants).

When you then log in and you have an url stored in your session, I redirect you with `Redirect::to(https://page.com/post/23)`

In first two cases there is no problem, but when I use `Redirect::to(https://page.com/post/23?show=full)` GET params are ignored.

Is there an option to redirect to url with GET params included?

Answer (score 1):

There's problem with your application. If I understand you correctly, your query parameters (such as: `?param=true&param2=1`) are not present in your url after redirect.

Consider the following example:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return Redirect::to('http://localhost:8000/test2?with=params');
});

Route::get('/test2', function () {
    echo '1';
});
```

When I try to access: `localhost:8000/test` I get redirected to: `http://localhost:8000/test2?with=params`

Which is the expected behavior. Can you post an example where you do that redirect?

Also I'd suggest using: [Redirect::intended()](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users) which does exactly what you want by itself.

Comment: Is there any diference if I make Redirect in routes.php or in some controller? I dont think, or?

I have in my Controller this:
`if(Session::has('reqUrl')){
   $url = Session::get('reqUrl');
   //var_dump($url); --it return http://web.com/post/23?show=full
   Session::forget('reqUrl');
   return Redirect::to($url)->with('message', trans('a.user-successfully-logged'))->with('message-type', 'ok');
}`

So I dont know where is problem. 
Then, in routes (for post) I have only:
`Route::get('post/{id}', array('before', => 'locale|auth', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getPost'));`

Comment: @Autista_z There's no difference where you return `Redirect::to()`. Have you tried setting the url manually, instead of using `Session::get()` just for the sake of debugging?

Comment: I found my mistake, Im stupid.
I use SSL certificate, but i was saving url in session as **http** and no **https**, and then if filters is `if( ! Request::secure() )  {return Redirect::secure( Request::path() ); }` which does not pass further.

Comment: @Autista_z, nah, that happens to anyone. I just wanted to make sure you know that passing GET parameters with `Redirect::to()` is OK and the problem is local. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can pass it like https://page.com/post/23/showFull

And you can got it via following way:

```
Request::segment(3);
```

Comment: Yes, this is a solution, but not very efficient, because i would have to change a lot of methods. Application uses Get params in a lot of pages, so i would rather make something else.

Answer (score 0):

Why not Redirect::back()? The auth filter *should* be able to redirect all the non-authed requests to the login page, then Redirect::back() the user to the previous visited page.

Edit: [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security), not middleware.

Comment: There are no middlewares in Laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, By default this feature is available if you are using the auth middleware, as given below:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){

//authorized routes

});
```

**Example**

If the user without loging in, is accessing the url "example.com/User?abc=123", which is an authorized route.

Then the user will be redirected automatically to the login page.

After successful login the user will be automatically redirected to the url first requested ("example.com/User?abc=123")